# What is $5x^2×2x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help because it's for a project and I'm not sure if it's $10x^2$ to $10x^4$. Also I know how to do easy multiplication but i just can't figure the problem out.

Comment: Hint: $5x^2 = 5 \times x \times x$.

Comment: When you multiply, exponents add.

Answer (score 4):

$5x^2 = 5*x*x$

$2x = 2*x$

So $5x^2*2x = 5*x*x*2*x = (5*2)*(x*x*x) = 10x^3$.

A little practice and a little patience and it was soon become utterly obvious and second nature.

(To the point it will seem practically impossible to explain to someone else as you'll forget how it could ever not be obvious.)

===

Oh,.... if you don't know this rule

$x^n *x^m = x^{m+n}$

it's worth learning.

$x^n*x^m = (x*......*x)*(x*......*x)$ [the first $(x*...*x)$ has $n$ $x$s and the second has $m$ $x$s]

$= x*........... *x$ [has $n+m$ $x$s total]

$= x^{n+m}$

That is a *very* important rule worth knowing.

Answer (score 3):

Multiplication is **commutative** meaning that we can change the order of the multiplications, hence
$$5\times x^2 \times 2\times x = 5\times 2 \times x\times x^2 = 10 \times x\times x^2. $$

The next step is realizing that $x\times x^2 = x^3.$ An easy way to see this is to remember that $x^2 = x\times x$ and hence $x\times x^2 = x\times (x\times x) = x\times x\times x = x^3.$ In general, however we have that
$$x^n \times x^m = x^{n+m}$$
which you can uside in this situation with $n=1$ and $m=2$. The final result is then
$$5\times x^2 \times 2\times x = 10 \times x\times x^2 = 10x^3.$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x = x^{1}$.  Using the rule of exponents that 
$$x^mx^n = x^{mn}$$
where $m$ and $n$ are positive integers, we obtain $$x^2x = x^2x^1 = x^{2 + 1} = x^3$$
Hence, 
$$5x^2 \cdot 2x = 5 \cdot x^2 \cdot 2 \cdot x = 5 \cdot 2 \cdot x^2 \cdot x^1 = 10x^3$$
We can verify this by writing out all the factors.
$$5x^2 \cdot 2x = 5 \cdot x \cdot x \cdot 2 \cdot x = 5 \cdot 2 \cdot x \cdot x \cdot x = 10x^3$$

Answer (score 0):

$5x^2\times2x$

We can multiply these terms by writing the like terms together as-

$(5\times2)\times(x^2\times x)$

$\implies$ $10\times(x^2\times x)$

$\implies$ $10\times(x^2\times x^1)\;\;\;\;$ $(\because a^1=a)$

$\implies$ $10\times(x^{2+1})\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$ $(\because a^m\times a^n=a^{m+n})$

$\implies$ $10\times x^3$

Thus, $5x^2\times2x=10x^3$